# Отсутствие return

Tags: java, функции, методы

Почему после последней фигурной скобки есть эта ошибка:`missing return statement`
Весь код:

```
    Double delo2() {
    a = Integer.parseInt(getTextFromEdit());
    b = Integer.parseInt(getTextFromEdit());
    double x=1;
    if (a > 0) {
        x = b / a;
        return x;
    } else if (a == 0) {
        x = 0;
        return x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Потому что `a` может быть меньше нуля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что компилятор не уверен, что хотя бы одно из условий выполнится. Например, если `a` будет меньше нуля.  А поэтому необходим еще один `return` в конце метода.

---

Вообще, чтобы не путаться, в некоторых случаях лучше сразу поставить `return Something` в конце метода, а внутри метода нужной переменной в нужный момент присваивать значения. Примерно так:

```
Double delo2() {        
    double x = 1;

    if (.....) {
        x = .......;            
    } else if (.........) {
        x = ......;            
    }

    return x;
}
```

Comment: Хм. Но в таком случае (один return в конце) компилятор не подскажет нам, если случайно забыть одну из возможных веток. Скомпилируется оно на ура, но будет неправильно работать.

Comment: @VladD, Тесты ?

Comment: @VladD забыть можно и слово, которое неоднократно употреблял в жизни. От этого никто не застрахован. А для нахождения причины работы по неожиданному сценарию всегда есть отладка/тесты

Comment: Ну, тесты как бы да. Но зачем тесты, если компилятор может подсказать? Мы ж как бы для этого используем строго типизированные языки — чтобы компилятор тыкал нас носом в ошибки. (Тем более, покрытие всей возможной логики тестами — утопия.)

Comment: @VladD я не знаю кто как пишет, но лично я не вижу смысла, если, например, имеется пять-шесть if'ов в котором может быть изменено значение возвращаемой переменной - писать везде `return переменная`. Считаю это избыточным, нерациональным и нецелесообразным.

Comment: Переменную можно не инициализировать при объявлении, тогда компилятор напишет на "return x" что переменная может быть не инициализирована, в случае если забыли одну из возможных веток.